# double distance tikz has no effect (beamer presentation)

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer

This is my frame:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Reactant distribution \\and finite Larmor radius effect}
\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item changes in $\mathbf{k_p}$ affect the \textbf{cut-off energy} of the\tikz\node [coordinate] (n1) {}; reactant energy distribution
\item \textbf{only} the \textbf{upward} gyro-\tikz\node [coordinate] (n2) {};motion is seen by the detector 
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}
\vspace{-0.3cm}
\centering
\tikz{\node [anchor=base] (t3) 
{\includegraphics[height=0.45\textheight]{pics/totspectrum.png}};
}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\begin{column}[t]{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\vspace{-5.4cm}
\centering
\tikz{\node [anchor=base] (t1) {\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{pics/distro_kp.png}};}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\vspace{-1.1cm}
\tikz{\node [anchor=base] (t2) {\includegraphics[height=0.5\textheight]{pics/orbit.png}};}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \path[->]<1-> (n1) edge [color=orange, out=0, in=180] (t1);
        \path[->]<1-> (n2) edge [color=orange, out=-30, in=150] (t2);
        \path[thin,double distance=5pt,->] <1-> (t2) edge [out=180,in=0](t3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

The problem is the arrow between (t2) and (t3). I want an arrow with double line, with visible distance between the lines. It should have the meaning "implies that". I made several tries changing the value of double dstance but nothing change: what I see is always a very thin arrow where I can not see that it is double. Could you help me? Thank you everyone.

Comment: Use `double` or `double distance=.5pt` as `edge` option: `edge[out=180,in=0,double distance=.5pt]`

Comment: @esdd Would you like to convert you comment into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

with use of `\tikzmark` and defined edge as

```
every edge/.append style = {very thick, -{Triangle[angle=60:1pt 3]}}
```

you can draw double line as

```
    \path   (pic cs:g2) edge [semithick, double distance=3pt, 
                              out=180,in=345] (pic cs:g3);
```

gives after added missing code an with use of `\tikzmark`s the following result:

[image]

*mwe*:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, tikzmark}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Reactant distribution \\and finite Larmor radius effect}
    \vspace{-2em}
\begin{columns}[t]
\small
\begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{itemize}
\item changes in $\mathbf{k_p}$ affect the \textbf{cut-off energy} of the
\tikzmark{n1} reactant energy distribution
\item \textbf{only} the \textbf{upward} gyro-\tikzmark{n2}motion is seen by the detector
\end{itemize}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth,valign=m]{example-image-a}\tikzmark{g3}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
%
\begin{column}{0.48\textwidth}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\tikzmark{g1}\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth,valign=m]{example-image-b}

\smallskip
\tikzmark{g2}\includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth,valign=m]{example-image-c}
\end{figure}
\end{column}
\end{columns}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay,
    every edge/.append style = {very thick, -{Triangle[angle=60:1pt 3]}}
                    ]
        \path   (pic cs:n1) edge [orange, out=  0, in=180] (pic cs:g1);
        \path   (pic cs:n2) edge [orange, out=-30, in=150] ([yshift=3mm] pic cs:g2);
        \path   (pic cs:g2) edge [semithick, double distance=3pt,
                                  out=180,in=345] (pic cs:g3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```